# System.in.read method does not throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when read length is larger than destination length

Tags: java, exception

I'm reading the book [Java™ I/O, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527501.do) and there's this code:

```
try {
  byte[] b = new byte[10];
  System.in.read(b);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
  System.err.println("Couldn't read from System.in!");
}
```

Quoting from the book:

> "..there's nothing to stop you from trying to read more data into the
>   array than will fit. If you do this, read( ) throws an
>   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.."

But when I run this code and enter more then 10 characters, no `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown; why is that the case?

Comment: Did you check by printing b to see how bytes are there?

Comment: yes I did, b holds the 10 first characters from my input, as expected, but no exception has been thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book is wrong and it is also poorly expressed. The following two statements are mutually contradictory:

> "..there's nothing to stop you from trying to read more data into the
>   array than will fit. If you do this, read( ) throws an
>   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException."

I don't know why Elliotte Rusty Harold thinks an exception is 'nothing to stop you'. It does stop you, and that is its purpose.

The truth of it is that `InputStream.read()` will read at least 1 and at most `b.length` bytes, unless it detects EOS instead and returns -1.

If you use the `read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)` overload it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if "off[set] is negative, len[gth] is negative, or len[gth] is greater than b[uffer].length - off[set]".

Comment: You're right, there is no logic in that sentence and if an exception is thrown it will clearly stop me.. and the quoting from the docs makes it perfectly clear

Answer (score 6):

Check the docs for [`InputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29):

> The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to the length of b

So the `read` call abides by the length of the array and limits the number of bytes actually read to that length. When you enter more than e.g. 10 characters, those additional characters will remain in the input stream. Do another `read` and you'll see them.

You *can* cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` using [`InputStream.read(array, offset, length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29).